# How to compose a string and an int to a string?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, iostream

At work we had to replace iostream with a function `void output(std::string)` :

```
std::cout << "This is some output." << '\n';

<--Old--
--New-->

output("This is some output");
```

Of course I have a lot of code where I combine a string and an int, and I already have found one possible solution for this problem:

```
int some_value = 5
std::cout << "Some value: " << some_value << '\n';

<--Old--
--New-->

int some_value = 5;
std::stringstream tmp_stream;
tmp_stream << "Some value: " << some_value << '\n';
output(tmp_stream.str());
```

But I don't really like this solution, as it introduces two additional lines of code and an additional use-once variable. Do you know of any other possible solutions that are more elegant?

Comment: Bother.  I was in the process of suggesting the OP wrote an `output_stream` class, which sent the output to the function `output`.  Either by doing it properly via a streambuf, or just by writing a class which had a bunch of  `operator <<`.  That way they just need to change `std::cout` to `g_output`.  Can't write that answer because the question has been closed as duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for the response!

Comment: @johannesmik A more generic version than the linked duplicate or the answers here would be to create a variadic function template, see for instance http://ideone.com/eVjnbv (the commented block is for c++17). This way you simply have to convert `std::cout << a << b << c;` to `to_output(a, b, c);`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to convert numeric types into `std::string`, then concatenate them before calling `output`

```
output("Some value: " + std::to_string(some_value));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just simply use the [std::to_string(value)](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) function and combine two std::string